# CakePHP 1.3 automatically log user out

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've set my Cakephp 1.3 debug level to 0 and whenever a user logs in, the user is automatically logged out after a few seconds.

However, this does not occur in debug level 1 or 2.

I've checked my security.level and session.timeout in core.php. I've also checked my server's php.ini and everything seems to be in order.

Anything that I could have missed out?

Comment: If I remember correctly it was a whitespace after close tag issue that someone in the irc channel had before with this same problem.

Comment: Hi, may I know which close tag are you referring to? Thanks.

Comment: php close tag in one of your files possibly

Comment: get the shell script that checks for whitespace - http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1837474952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this fixed. I used the shell script to check for whites pace as well as manually eyeballing through my entire app. From models down to my views.

Cleaned up the entire code and made sure there wasn't any unnecessary whitespace or unused methods such as debug and it's working fine now. I guess clean coding does help in getting your app run smoothly.